# My page repeats its header and other divs when using jquery code for automatic updates for a particular div

Tags: php, jquery

I recently learnt- Auto refreshing a div on your page using Jquery. My code looks like.

```
setInterval(function() {
$("#aaa").load(location.href+"#aaa>*","");
}, 10000); // seconds to wait, miliseconds
```

Where #aaa is div I want to automatic update. But What happens is when I apply this code - My navigation bar repeats itself and other div on the same page too. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing a space between the URL and the div selector in your load argument.

Here is the example for loading page fragments from https://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

Comment: Okay, I want to update the content of a page iteself. Not from an external page. How to do it ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Assuming the only error with your original code is syntax, maybe replacing the load line with the following will do what you want: $("#aaa").load(location.href+" #aaa>");

Comment: $("#aaa").load(location.href+" #aaa");     actually, make it this.  the > shouldn't be there.

Comment: Workd ! :) . I removed > . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to refresh the content of the div every 10 sec.

you can clear the content before you place your call so it does not add it to it like this

```
    setInterval(function() {
       $("#aaa").html(''); 
       $("#aaa").load(location.href+"#aaa>*","");
        }, 10000); // seconds to wait, miliseconds
```